# How is the center point of an arc path determined?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having some difficulty drawing an arc as part of a path.  What I'd like to do is draw a whole ellipse then shade only part of it.  The shaded part is defined by four points on the ellipse.  I can do this by clipping, but I'd like to understand from where the `arc` path is subtended.  Additionally, it seems like drawing the path with arcs would be a better option since I can use the `cycle` path operation at the end and, ideally, it would cover up the dashed ellipse.

Example code as a starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={font=\footnotesize},
                    >=latex]

  \draw (0, 0) [dashed, name path=footprint] circle [x radius=2, y radius=4];
  \path [name path=top slice] (-2, 1) -- (2, 1);
  \path [name path=bottom slice] (-2, -1) -- (2, -1);

  \path [name intersections={of=footprint and {top slice}, name=top}];
  \path [name intersections={of=footprint and {bottom slice},
                             name=bottom}];

  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
    \pgfpointorigin}{%
    \pgfpointanchor{top-1}{center}}
  \let\angleorigr\pgfmathresult

  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
    \pgfpointorigin}{%
    \pgfpointanchor{bottom-2}{center}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleendr}{\pgfmathresult - 360}

  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
    \pgfpointorigin}{%
    \pgfpointanchor{top-2}{center}}
  \let\angleendl\pgfmathresult

  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
    \pgfpointorigin}{%
    \pgfpointanchor{bottom-1}{center}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleorigl}{\pgfmathresult}

  % It should look something like:
  %\begin{scope}
  %  \path [clip] (-2, 1) -- (2, 1) -- (2, -1) -- (-2, -1) --
  %    cycle;
  %  \path [clip] (0, 0) circle [x radius=2, y radius=4];
  %  \filldraw [fill=lightgray, fill opacity=0.5]
  %    (-2, 1) -- (2, 1) (2, -1) -- (-2, -1)
  %    (0, 0) circle [x radius=2, y radius=4];
  %\end{scope}

  % Using arcs it looks crazy:
  \draw [fill=lightgray, opacity=0.5]
    (top-2) -- (top-1)
    arc [x radius=2, y radius=4, start angle=\angleorigr,
    end angle=\angleendr]
    (bottom-2) -- (bottom-1)
    arc [x radius=2, y radius=4, start angle=\angleorigl,
    end angle=\angleendl];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So how is the "center point" of the arc component determined (please modify this example to show the path can be generated using arcs)?

Comment: The center for an arc seems to be at `($(<current point of the path>)+({-<x radius>*cos(<start angle>)},{-<y radius>*sin(<start angle>)})$)`. One way would be to `moveto` that point before drawing the arc, but that would break filling, I think.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem with getting the arc to cover the right portion of the ellipse is that the `start angle` and `end angle` are assumed to be angles on the edge of a circle, not on the edge of an ellipse. In this application, an ellipse is basically a squashed circle. The angle you're calculating is too large, since you're implicitly assuming that points on the circle are projected radially onto the ellipse:

[image]

I've written a new TikZ key `correct ellipse angles` that corrects the start and end angles according to the `x radius` and `y radius` of the ellipse. It lets you write

```
\draw [fill=lightgray!50]
    (top-2) -- (top-1) let \p1 = (top-1) in
    arc [x radius=2, y radius=4, start angle=\angleorigr, end angle=\angleendr, correct ellipse angles]
   -- (bottom-2) --  (bottom-1) 
    arc [x radius=2, y radius=4, start angle=\angleorigl, end angle=\angleendl, correct ellipse angles=360 ]
;
```

to give

[image]

The optional parameter can be used to correct for negative angles that would lead to the arc going the wrong way.

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={font=\footnotesize},
                    >=latex]

  \draw (0, 0) [dashed, name path=footprint] circle [x radius=2, y radius=4];
  \path [name path=top slice] (-2, 1) -- (2, 1);
  \path [name path=bottom slice] (-2, -1) -- (2, -1);

  \path [name intersections={of=footprint and {top slice}, name=top}];
  \path [name intersections={of=footprint and {bottom slice},
                             name=bottom}];

  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
    \pgfpointorigin}{%
    \pgfpointanchor{top-1}{center}}
  \let\angleorigr\pgfmathresult

  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
    \pgfpointorigin}{%
    \pgfpointanchor{bottom-2}{center}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleendr}{\pgfmathresult}

  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
    \pgfpointorigin}{%
    \pgfpointanchor{top-2}{center}}
  \let\angleendl\pgfmathresult

  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
    \pgfpointorigin}{%
    \pgfpointanchor{bottom-1}{center}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleorigl}{\pgfmathresult}


\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    correct ellipse angles/.code={
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/start angle}\start@angle
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/end angle}\end@angle
        \pgfmathsetmacro\corrected@startangle{atan2(cos(\start@angle)/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/x radius},sin(\start@angle)/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius})}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\corrected@endangle{atan2(cos(\end@angle)/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/x radius},sin(\end@angle)/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius})}
        \tikzset{/tikz/start angle=\corrected@startangle+#1, end angle=\corrected@endangle}
    },
    correct ellipse angles/.default=0
}
\makeatother


\draw [fill=lightgray!50]
    (top-2) -- (top-1) let \p1 = (top-1) in
    arc [x radius=2, y radius=4, start angle=\angleorigr, end angle=\angleendr, correct ellipse angles]
   -- (bottom-2) --  (bottom-1) 
    arc [x radius=2, y radius=4, start angle=\angleorigl, end angle=\angleendl, correct ellipse angles=360 ]
;



\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw ellipse [x radius=2cm, y radius=2cm];
\draw (2cm,0pt) -- (0,0) -- (63:2cm) (0,0) -- (45:2cm);
\draw [line width=6pt,opacity=0.5,orange] (2cm, 0pt) arc [x radius=2cm, y radius=2cm, start angle=0, end angle=63];
\draw [line width=6pt,opacity=0.5,cyan] (2.2cm, 0pt) arc [x radius=2.2cm, y radius=2.2cm, start angle=0, end angle=45];
\fill [blue,x=1cm,y=1cm] (1.41,1.41) circle [radius=2pt];

\draw ellipse [x radius=1cm, y radius=2cm];
\draw [line width=6pt,opacity=0.5,orange] (1cm, 0pt) arc [x radius=1cm, y radius=2cm, start angle=0, end angle=63];
\draw [line width=6pt,opacity=0.5,cyan] (1.2cm, 0pt) arc [x radius=1.2cm, y radius=2.2cm, start angle=0, end angle=45];

\fill [red,x=0.5cm,y=1cm] (1.41,1.41) circle [radius=2pt];
\node at (60:2cm) [pin={[text width=3cm]75:You're measuring\\this angle\ldots}] {};
\node at (25:2.2cm) [pin={[text width=3cm]75:\ldots but you want this one}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Not only for the answer but also for the progression. Deserves more than 1 upvote.

Comment: The crucial conceptual thing is that the angle should be interpreted as the *parameter* of the arc.  So I would name your new keys "geometric angle" rather than "correct angle" to make that point.  That said, I completely agree with percusse.

Comment: The first graphic speaks volumes, thanks for the detail.

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer to the title of your question. A precise answer for your particular needs more reflection: see @Jake's comprehensive answer.

The center for an arc seems to be at

```
($(<current point of the path>) + 
  ({-<x radius>*cos(<start angle>)},{-<y radius>*sin(<start angle>)})$)
```

Let's carry out some experiments.

First circle arcs:

[image: Circle arcs]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\def\Radius{3}%
\def\StartAngle{30}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[Point/.style = {%
    circle,fill=red,inner sep=0.5pt}]
  \node[Point,label=above:$O$] (O) at (0,0) {};
  % O is the center of the blue circle
  \draw[blue] (O) circle[radius=\Radius];
  % ($(O)+(-\Radius,0)$) is the center of the green circle
  \node[Point,label=above:$O_1$] (O1) at ($(O)+(-\Radius,0)$) {};
  \draw[green] (O) arc[radius=\Radius,start angle=0,delta angle=360];
  % ($(O)+(\StartAngle:-\Radius)$) is the center of the yellow circle
  \node[Point,label=above:$O_2$] (O2) at
    ($(O)+(\StartAngle:-\Radius)$) {}; 
  \draw[yellow] (O) arc[radius=\Radius,start angle=\StartAngle,delta
    angle=390]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then elliptic arcs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\def\RadiusX{3}%
\def\RadiusY{4}%
\def\StartAngle{30}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[Point/.style = {%
    circle,fill=red,inner sep=0.5pt}]
  \node[Point,label=above:$O$] (O) at (0,0) {};
  % O is the center of the blue ellipse
  \draw[blue] (O) circle[x radius=\RadiusX,y radius=\RadiusY];
  % ($(O)+(-\RadiusX,0)$) is the center of the green ellipse
  \node[Point,label=above:$O_1$] (O1) at ($(O)+(-\RadiusX,0)$) {};
  \draw[green] (O) arc[x radius=\RadiusX,y radius=\RadiusY,start
    angle=0,delta angle=360]; 
  \draw[green] ($(O1)+(0,-\RadiusY)$) -- ($(O1)+(0,\RadiusY)$);
  \draw[green] ($(O1)+(-\RadiusX,0)$) -- ($(O1)+(\RadiusX,0)$);
  % ($(O)+({-\RadiusX*cos(\StartAngle)},{-\RadiusY*sin(\StartAngle)})$) 
  % is the center of the black ellipse  
  \node[Point,label=above:$O_2$] (O2) at
    ($(O)+({-\RadiusX*cos(\StartAngle)},{-\RadiusY*sin(\StartAngle)})$) {}; 
  \draw (O) arc[x radius=\RadiusX,y radius=\RadiusY,start
  angle=\StartAngle,delta angle=360]; 
  \draw ($(O2)+(0,-\RadiusY)$) -- ($(O2)+(0,\RadiusY)$);
  \draw ($(O2)+(-\RadiusX,0)$) -- ($(O2)+(\RadiusX,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While technically an answer to the title of the question, I'm not sure how to phrase it differently.